# Automatic Conference Freeswitch calling to multiple callers depending on caller

Tags: freeswitch

I am new to Freeswitch. Is it possible that a specific user calls on a number, which results to a conference call. And system adds multiple people to this conference call automatically. e.g.

User "A" calls at 5656. And whenever user A calls at this no, then the dial plan will begin a conference. And User B,C and D will automatically added to this conference. How will the dial plan look like.

Is it possible to mute all except the caller automatically. Can somebody share Dial plan for both of these things?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check mod_conference conference_set_auto_outcall

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Conference_set_auto_outcall

The conference is anyway started by an extension, if you use dial plans. When conference_set_auto_outcall can call some predefined numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to issue an `originate` command after your conference is established. Then it will make outgoing calls and join them into the bridge. See `mod_conference` documentation on FreeSWITCH wiki.

I think the easiest way to do so is to write a Lua script and execute it from your dialplan.

As far as I know, there's no ready-made piece of configuration, you either need to learn it yourself or pay someone to implement it.